# Как выбрать только русские слова из списка в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

У меня есть список слов как на английском так и на русском.
Например

```
list = ['apple', 'cat', 'яблоко', 'кот', 'building', 'машина', 'status',]
```

Как можно пройдя циклом вывести только русские слова?
В будущем планируется перебирать большой объем данных. И как это можно сделать с учетом производительности?

Answer (score 6):

Можно сделать через регулярное выражение, например:

```
import re

r = re.compile("[а-яА-Я]+")
words = ['apple', 'cat', 'яблоко', 'кот', 'building', 'машина', 'status',]
russian = [w for w in filter(r.match, words)]
```

Для повышения скорости фильтрации на многоядерном процессоре можно дробить исходный список слов на куски (скажем, по 100000) и запускать фильтрацию в отдельных потоках с последующей конкатенацией результатов в один список.

Comment: В регулярке, пожалуй, плюс не нужен. А вообще, правильный ответ - никак. Вот слово `"appлоко"` - оно русское или нерусское? (a, p, p - латиница). Можно фильтровать по наличию хотя бы одной русской буквы в слове, можно фильтровать по наличию в слове ТОЛЬКО русских букв `r = re.compile("^[а-яА-Я]+$")`]. Корректно фильтровать только слова русского языка можно только с помощью полного словаря языка.

Comment: регулярное выражение в ответе (`"[а-яА-Я]+"`) разрешает любую строку, которая начинается с  `[а-я]` -- поэтому оно может вернуть строки, которые не состоят только из русских букв, например: `яQ`.

Comment: @andy.37: можно `re.fullmatch()` использовать. Кстати, `^[а-яА-Я]+$` в этом случае неверно, так как исключает `'ёж'`

Comment: это непростительно, что под Новый Год, слово "ёлка" не распознаётся (`а-я` не включает `ё`).

Comment: @jfs, да, совсем забыл об этом любопытном факте. Кстати, регулярка `[а-я]` разрешает любую строку, которая СОДЕРЖИТ хотя бы одну русскую букву (не начинается). И еще, фраза `художник Петров-Водкин` состоит из русских слов?

Comment: @andy.37: почитайте что метод `match()` делает

Answer (score 4):

Простой вариант:

```
[word for word in lst if 1039 < ord(word[0])]
```

P.S.: Не стоит использовать имя переменной `list`, в языке уже есть одноименная функция.

Update: Протестировал производительность - решение на регулярных выражениях работает на порядок быстрее.

Comment: Хороший вариант, подразумевающий "если первая буква русская - все слово русское".

Comment: @andy.37: вариант с regex так и работает *"если первая буква русская - все слово русское"*, то есть данные ответ не теряет общности по сравнению с [ответом @ Vitali Falileev](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/477165/23044)

Comment: это также предполагает, что английские слова не имеют лигатур, различных комбинирующих символов итд.

Comment: @jfs это не так. см комментарий к его ответу.

Comment: @andy.37: вы ошибайтесь.

Comment: @jfs, ошибаюсь, вечно путаю `match` и `search` в питоне. С регулярками просто предпочитаю в `perl` работать, он просто создан для этого.