# Как можно определить язык текста на windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть список из русских и английских слов вперемешку, нужно разделить его на 2 словаря. Один словарь содержит все русские слова, второй все английские. Как это сделать на windows?

```py
li = ['dog', 'cat', 'собака', 'кот']
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477161/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-python?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 alphabet = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
 li = ['dog', 'cat', 'собака', 'кот']
 rus = {}
 engl = {}

for word in li:
   for w in word:
    if w in alphabet:
        rus[word]=''
        rus.update()
    else:
        engl[word] =''
        engl.update()


print('*',rus)
print('**',engl)
```